# XSLT and XPath libraries for .NET Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, xpath, compact-framework

anybody can suggest me a library or C# code for .net compact framework 3.5 to perform XSL Transformations and/or xpath navigations?

Before you start typing please note that my needs are for .NET COMPACT FRAMEWORK, I know that the full framework has classes for this. Note also that I tried and found that the System.Xml.Linq.XDocument and related classes are not concerned to XSLT and XPath.

So, thanx in advance!!!

Comment: From the off-topic flagging menu: `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: @admdrew Well, at least half of his question is actually possible within the Compact Framework. The asker was just unaware.

Comment: Hi Alan and thanx for your comment and answer. I'm aware about SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode but that's not what I'm looking for, I meant the compact framework doesn't have the XPath API like the namespace XPath with navigator classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I found that I can use the Interop.MSXML2.dll library in Compact Framework for XSLT transforming. Here is an example code:

```
// Apply XSLT transform
var domXml = new DOMDocument();
domXml.loadXML(xml);
string xsltPath = "file.xslt";
var domXslt = new DOMDocument();
using (var xsltReader = new StreamReader(xsltPath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    domXslt.loadXML(xsltReader.ReadToEnd());
}
string transformedXml = domXml.transformNode(domXslt.documentElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select nodes using XPath in the Compact Framework using `XmlDocument.SelectNodes` and `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode` which both take an XPath.

As far as finding an XSLT library, I would just be searching for one like you. It depends on what operating system you are using. You could P/Invoke a native library like MSXML on Windows Mobile 5.0 for example.

Comment: Hi Alan and thanx for your comment and answer. I'm aware about SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode but that's not what I'm looking for, I meant the compact framework doesn't have the XPath API like the namespace XPath with navigator classes.

Comment: @hdkrus Which O/S are you on?

Comment: the OS is Windows CE 5.0